# Sharing state between two async programs in python using asyncio and contextvars

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-contextvars

I currently have two infinite asynchronous tasks running and want to share state between them. One task is a websocket connection that reads in messages then sends messages and the other reads in incoming light data. I want to send a boolean between the two tasks that says whether or not the websocket connection is successful.

Here is how I'm initializing the context.

```
client_connect_var = contextvars.ContextVar('client_connect',default = False)
client_connect_var.set(False)
ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
async def main():
  message = json.dumps({'payload': {
                        'payload'})
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  start_light = asyncio.create_task(calculate_idle(3))
  await asyncio.gather(init_connection(message), start_light)

ctx.run(asyncio.run(main()))
```

Here is my code in my init_connection:

```
async def init_connection(message):
  async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
      #This should set the global context variable to true
      client_connect_var.set(True)
      CLIENT_WS = websocket
      client_connect = client_connect_var.get()
    # send init message
    await websocket.send(message)
    print("Connection is open")
    while client_connect:
        await handleMessages(websocket, message)
    await websocket.close()
```

Here is where it's trying to get the current state in the light code

```
async def calculate_idle(t):
    orig_time = t
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        #This should be true, but it's false
        client_connect = client_connect_var.get()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

In calculate_idle, the variable in the context is still set to false. I'm not sure how to get it to be set to true from inside init_connection. I'd like to expand this to updating other values in state that are objects. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you reduce the code to the minimum amount required to reflect what is happening?

Comment: Yeah, I'll reduce it a bit

Comment: Why are you using `ctx = contextvars.copy_context()` and then `ctx.run(asyncio.run(main()))`?

Comment: I thought I was copying the original context with the variable then running the main inside that copied context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ContextVar` serves the purpose **opposite** of what you're trying to use it for: it's for data that is **local** to a task, something like a "task-local" global variable.

To share data between two tasks you can use normal Python sharing mechanisms, e.g. a global variable or an ordinary mutable value (e.g. a dict or an instance of a class of your choosing). You can also use synchronization like `asyncio.Event` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) to notify the other task when the value changes.

Comment: When I tried using a global variable, I was having the same issue of it not updating. I'm not sure if using asyncio.create_task put it in a different context? It seemed the global variable would be initially set, then get changed in the init_connection, but would still be the initial value in calculate_idle.

Comment: @avenmia Did you update the variable correctly? Have you used `print`s to check that the code was actually being executed? Such things should work, there is nothing magical about asyncio (at that level) that would prohibit such state sharing from working.

Comment: I just reverted back to using a global variable and using prints to check that it's being executed and it is. I first, initialize global variable to false, in init_connection I use the global keyword to get the variable. When it is connected I print ("connection set to true") and set the global to true. In the while true in calculate_idle I print the state of the global variable and it remains false.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but I noticed when I print the addresses of the global variable in both spots, they have different addresses.

Comment: @avenmia Can you please show the code that uses the globals?

Comment: Yeah would it be easier to ask in a different question with global variables instead?

Comment: @avenmia Good point, I guess editing the question and posting a new one are both valid approaches, so it's up to you. It might well turn out that the real problem was elsewhere in the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801288/how-to-update-global-variable-in-asyncio-create-task updated question for using a global here.Thank you for your help!

Comment: @avenmia Python's global variables are actually module-local; see my answer to the other question.